# Pretty Print object in Swift on debug area

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I am new to swift. I am trying to find a way to accomplish that.
In objective-c project, when I NSLog a response body from api, I got something like this. its pretty and readable. [Ojective-c Debug area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tli7.png)
However, when i use swift, when I print a response body from api, I got something like that. It's super hard to read. [Swift Debug area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8Kle.png)
is there any way in swift, i could see the same format in debug area same as objective-c project.
If anyone could help, I really appreciate.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It mainly depends on what you're trying to print in the Debug area. From Apple docs:

> Swift provides a default debugging textual representation for any type. That default representation is used by the String(reflecting:) initializer and the debugPrint(_:) function for types that don’t provide their own.

From the image you've linked, it looks like you're printing a Dictionary, which prints out like that and there's not a straightforward way to change it. Considering you're getting data from an API, you can do debugging in three ways:

1. Print the raw body: if your server is returning JSON, that's usually readable and, in case it isn't, there are many JSON formatters/viewers online.
2. Parse the response into instances of a class that you define as conforming to `CustomDebugStringConvertible`; then, print the resulting array. *This will not work in case the server response is malformed*.
3. Loop through the dictionary and manually print keys and values in a format that looks readable to you.